# MySql Workbench Couldn't find section mysqld in the remote config file /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-workbench, ubuntu, remote

if you get this trying to connect to your remote server using MySql Workbench, then try to (on your remote server) navigate to /etc/mysql/my.cnf
and add

```
[mysqld]
```

then it should look like:

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
[mysqld]
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

Comment: (Rephrase as a Question, then self-Answer it; you will get more reputation points.)

Comment: Note: MySQL Workbench does **not** evaluate includes currently (8.0.16). Only the main config file is read.

Comment: Why should it look like that? On my machine, the [mysqld] definition is in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf, and I would assume that the `!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/` command looks for it inside that folder.